# Delphi Interbase Sql Conversion to Sql Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, firebird, interbase

i have a delphi application which uses database
interbase / firebird. To consult and write data I use the
InterBase components palette (IBTable, IBQuery, IBDataset). I'm
performing the conversion of my system to sqlserver / Oracle but i have
thousands of queries that are assembled at runtime with SQL Instructions
Specific of database InterBase/Firebird. Anyone know
any component or tool that makes Parse commands Interbase -> SQL Server or Interbase-> Oracle ?

what i need its something like:

```
Var
  Parser: TParser;
  OutputSql: String;
Begin
   Parser := TParser.Create();
   Parser.Text := 'SELECT FIRST 10 CITYNAME FROM TBCITY';

   if Firebird then
      OutPutSql := Parser.ParseTo('SQLSERVER');

   if Oracle then
      OutPutSql := Parser.ParseTo('ORACLE');

   ComponentAccess.Sql.Text := OutPutSql;
   ...
```

The Result Of:

```
Parser.ParseTo('SQLSERVER');
```

Will Be

'SELECT TOP 10 CITYNAME FROM TBCITY'

And

```
Parser.ParseTo('ORACLE');
```

Will Be

'SELECT CITYNAME FROM TBCITY WHERE ROWNUM <= 10'

Answer (score 3):

1) AFAIK, libraries like AnyDAC, have [SQL abstraction syntax](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Macros_and_escape_sequences.html). May be you can use this feature in your SQL command text.

2) If you are assembling your SQL at runtime, then why not just code like that:

```
if Firebird then
  SQL.Add(...)
else if Oracle then
  SQL.Add(...)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

We have implemented that in AnyDAC. You may use LIMIT escape function:

```
ADQuery1.Sql.Text := 'SELECT {LIMIT(10)} CITYNAME FROM TBCITY';
```

AnyDAC will automatically translate that into target DBMS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have used kbmMW from [Components4Developers](http://www.components4developers.com) and it has an abstracted set of queries that provide macros and the like to enable /easier/ cross database work but it's mainly for client/server use. [Devart](http://www.devart.com) also do a good set of [cross database components](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) - we use their [SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/sdac/) set. However, each project I've done I've ended up writing a specific set of SQL scripts for each database. Obviously there is a fair bit of common ground for simple select stuff but the feature sets of the different databases are often too different to make it easily workable.

I end up with something similar to @oodesigner's response except that we use $ifdef and define my SQL strings in a separate const unit.

```
{$ifdef USE_MSSQL}
  QUERY_ONE = 'select blah blah blah...';
{$else}
  QUERY_ONE = 'select nah nah nah...';
{$endif}
```

Then in the main unit a simple assignment

```
SQL.Text := QUERY_ONE;
```

or

```
SQL.Text := Format(QUERY_TWO, [some_very_carefully_quoted_stuff_or_use_params]);
```

Don't know of anything that would automate or parse it. And the problem with that is that you still have to go through and check *every single query* because it's too easy to get things wrong when converting.